# Hive table in Spark

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I am running following job in HDP.

```
export SPARK-MAJOR-VERSION=2
spark-submit --class com.spark.sparkexamples.Audit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster \
--files /bigdata/datalake/app/config/metadata.csv BRNSAUDIT_v4.jar dl_raw.ACC /bigdatahdfs/landing/AUDIT/BW/2017/02/27/ACC_hash_total_and_count_20170227.dat TH 20170227
```

Its failing with error that:

```
*Table or view not found: `dl_raw`.`ACC`; line 1 pos 94;
'Aggregate [count(1) AS rec_cnt#58L, 'count('BRCH_NUM) AS hashcount#59, 'sum('ACC_NUM) AS hashsum#60]
+- 'Filter (('trim('country_code) = trim(TH)) && ('from_unixtime('unix_timestamp('substr('bus_date, 0, 11), MM/dd/yyyy), yyyyMMdd) = 20170227))
   +- 'UnresolvedRelation `dl_raw`.`ACC'*
```

Whereas table is present in Hive and it is accessible from spark-shell.

UPD.

```
    val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder
.appName("spark session example")
.enableHiveSupport()
.getOrCreate() 
sparkSession.conf.set("spark.sql.crossJoin.enabled", "true") 

val df_table_stats = sparkSession.sql("""select count(*) as rec_cnt,count(distinct BRCH_NUM) as hashcount,
sum(ACC_NUM) as hashsum 
from dl_raw.ACC 
where trim(country_code) = trim('BW') 
and from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(substr(bus_date,0,11),'MM/dd/yy‌​yy'),'yyyyMMdd')='20‌​170227'""")
```

Comment: share your code? Do you access it using hive context?

Comment: val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder      
      .appName("spark session example")
      .enableHiveSupport()
      .getOrCreate()
  sparkSession.conf.set("spark.sql.crossJoin.enabled", "true")
val df_table_stats = sparkSession.sql("select count(*) as rec_cnt,count(distinct BRCH_NUM) as hashcount,sum(ACC_NUM) as hashsum from dl_raw.ACC where trim(country_code) = trim('BW') and from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(substr(bus_date,0,11),'MM/dd/yyyy'),'yyyyMMdd')='20170227'")

Comment: I am using spark 2, so i guess hiveContext is not mandatory.

I got following links but not sure exactly how to use.
https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/24654/query-hive-tables-with-spark-sql.html
https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/5798/spark-hive-tables-not-found-when-running-in-yarn-c.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

include the hive-site.xml file in the --file parameter while submitting the job

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response. I am able to access same table in spark-shell. But with command as mentioned above. This is not working.